# MySQL 8 can view be deterministic view?

Tags: mysql

I made a huge jump from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 NDB. and it seems to me that in the earlier version when I queried a view I got answers more deterministic than now. Seems like it was ordered by something and now it does not.

It is not a huge problem but is my theory somewhat correct?

Thanks

Comment: yes it does, thanks

Comment: I'm curious.  What was the reason for switching to NDB?

Comment: for HA. We can not let any downtime for this database and all the data must be the latest possible at all times

Comment: Which mode of "eventually consistent" are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were *lucky* enough to get rows in "some order" consistently before, then you were just that ...   Lucky.

The rows in Relational Database Tables have *no deterministic order*.
The only way to *guarantee* the order of what you get back from a query (or a View, which is just a "Query with a Name") is to use the "**Order by**" Clause.